# Calculate a weighted average for several columns

Tags: mysql, r

I have a table, `table1`, containing multiple rows within each value of the column `ID`. I would like to calculate the same sort of weighed average using the same duration column `time` for a large number of columns.

I can manually define each column:

```
drop table if exists table2;
create table table2 as 
select ID, 
 sum(var1*time)/sum(time) as var1,
 sum(var2*time)/sum(time) as var2,
 sum(var3*time)/sum(time) as var3,
 sum(var4*time)/sum(time) as var4
 from table1 group by ID;
```

Is there a way to do this programmatically for a large number of columns?

Let's say I can use regex to identify the columns of interest. We can use the syntax var1, var2, var3 etc for this example.

Comment: I don't know what a variable is in this context

Comment: It's a column. My apologies for not using the correct mysql term.

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design. A table comprising of 3 columns (e,g. collection_id, var_number, var_value) might be easier to work with

Comment: Ok so it sounds like the only solution here is to reshape the data to long format?

Comment: I'm not going to say 'only', but I would be tempted to say 'best'

Comment: I'm leaning towards what @Strawberry said.  SQL is good for many things, but repeating patterns across columns is not one of them.  You may be able to "unpivot" your columns into rows, but that's also something that MySQL doesn't have a shortcut for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider building a vector of sum expressions, then `paste(..., collapse)` in larger SQL statement. Adjust `1:4` to actual variable range. Line breaks do not render in passed query.

```
sums <- paste0("  sum(var", 1:4, "*time)/sum(time) as var", 1:4)

sql <- paste0('select ID,\n',
              paste(sums, collapse = ', \n'), '\n',
              'from table1 \n', 
              'group by ID;')

cat(sql)
# select ID,
#   sum(var1*time)/sum(time) as var1, 
#   sum(var2*time)/sum(time) as var2, 
#   sum(var3*time)/sum(time) as var3, 
#   sum(var4*time)/sum(time) as var4
# from table1 
# group by ID;

channel <- odbcConnect("redacted",uid="redacted",case="nochange")
x <- sqlQuery(channel, sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat tongue-in-cheek but this is also what I literally had to do (in R):

```
library(RODBC)
library(data.table)
channel <- odbcConnect("redacted",uid="redacted",case="nochange")
x <- as.data.table(sqlQuery(channel, "select * from schema1.table1"))
vars <- grep("var", names(x), v=TRUE)
out <- x[,lapply(.SD, function(v){
  sum(v*time)/sum(time)
}),by=ppt_id, .SDcols=vars]
sqlSave(channel, as.data.frame(out), tablename="schema1.table2")
```

I'd still like to know how to do this in mysql.

Comment: This may be better to make as an edit to your original question (a "here is what I have so far") instead of making this an answer.

Comment: it's definitely an answer. It's just not the best answer.